# Preserve Leading Zeros in Excel Split Output

Tags: excel, vba

I will be in receipt of a weekly file in which a column must be Split using a "," delimiter, but in which the position of the target column and the length of the values in that column are unknown, and will vary.

Some of the values in the target column for the Split have leading 0's , which are currently being removed as you would expect if the characters were input to a column formatted as General. The target column for the Split is always formatted as Text prior to executing the Split. All values from columns other than the targeted column must be retained.

The target column appears to be converted to General instead of the intended Text format after the below procedure is run. I'm uncertain as to how to ensure the column remains Text and the leading 0's are preserved.

Current Sub:

```
Sub Test_Split_Column()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, LC As Integer
Dim x As Variant
Dim r As Range, iCol As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Set r = Application.InputBox("Click in the column to split by", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = " "
On Error GoTo 0
iCol = r.Column
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
Columns(iCol).Insert
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    With Cells(i, iCol + 1)
        If InStr(.Value, ",") = 0 Then
            .Offset(, -1).Value = .Value
        Else
            x = Split(.Value, ",")
            .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(x)).EntireRow.Insert
            .Offset(, -1).Resize(UBound(x) - LBound(x) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(x)
        End If
    End With
Next i
Columns(iCol + 1).Delete
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC))
    On Error Resume Next
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Value = .Value
End With
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Examples of Raw Data, Current Output, and Desired Output linked below:

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TCtA.png)

Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you can try formating the cells as text with `.NumberFormat = "@"` before assigning their values.

Comment: Also you can set your column as "`Text`" format

Comment: You might be able to use the `Range.TextToColumns` method and specify the columns as 'xlTextFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'` can be used to force excel to treat any value as text.

```
x = Split(Replace("'" & .Value, ",", ",'"), ",")
```

Comment: After replacing the current x = Split line, this returns the same result. Logically I would think that it shouldn't -- as you mentioned, the preceding "'" would normally force the value to be recognized as text, but it didn't seem to work in this instance.

Comment: it worked for me. i wrote a small piece of code, basically borrowed from yours, and it worked.

Comment: @Bnecrons090 I forgot about the first value. If the updated version doesn't work, make sure the `'` are not removed by Transpose or any other part of the code.

Comment: Thank you both! @Slai, it must be something else in the code, as I'm still getting the same result with the edited segment. Unfortunately, VBA is not my strong suite, so I suppose I'll need to keep fiddling around...

Comment: However, pending an extra ' to the front of the target column prior to executing the split seems to force the retaining of the 0's...if I'm reading the segment you posted correctly, that's essentially what it's already doing? If so, it has to be some other portion cancelling out that intended outcome. Ex: I did a forced concatenate up front with = "'"&C2 (copied down another column, then pasted over original with values). After re-running split, it retains the 0's.

Comment: Using this in addition to placing .NumberFormat = "@" above the .Value = .Value line ensures the values are recognized as text and the zeros preserved.Thanks, @Slai ! Very useful, and a great learning experience.

Comment: @Bnecrons090 I am glad that you figured it out. Seems unusual for both to be needed, so I am guessing that just the `.NumberFormat = "@"` should be enough. Also, some useful information on VBA debugging in the Documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a String array instead of a Variant array to a range, the values will be set as Strings even if the values are numeric.

Something like this should work.

```
   Dim strValue As String
   strValue = "000123,1234,0001"

   Dim x As Variant
   x = Split(strValue, ",")

   ReDim result(0 To UBound(x), 0 To 0) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 0 To UBound(x)
      result(i, 0) = x(i)
   Next i
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3").Value = result
```